# Customizing CKAN resource type labels

Tags: ckan

Currently using CKAN for our data catalog, but trying to figure out how to customize resource-type format labels on the Dataset page.

For example, on the Dataset landing page (e.g. http://demo.ckan.org/dataset), I see a list of my datasets as well as the associated resource (ZIP, PDF, XLS, etc.) types. Some resources have a color-coded label (e.g. XLS is green), but unfortunately, when someone adds a custom resource such as KML to the dataset, the label is grey. I assume the default is grey.

My question is, would it be possible to change the color of the resource label on the Dataset landing page to something other than gray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First, go to your admin config panel (it should be the `/ckan-admin/config` URI path of your instance) and there you will have a `Custom CSS` field.

You can find some sample colors in the CKAN [source code](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/b7204bb307abb1f488b5d409262db40b1e840d59/ckan/public/base/less/dataset.less#L174).

For changing KML to let's say green, add the following code to the CSS field:

```
.label[data-format=kml], .label[data-format*=kml] {
    background-color: #2db55d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code was what I needed. Also, is it possible to change the icon for custom resources? These icons show up on the dataset description page.

Comment: It's a little more complicated, but [here](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/b7204bb307abb1f488b5d409262db40b1e840d59/ckan/public/base/less/icons.less#L90) is the CSS code you have to override and [here](https://data.gov.ro/base/images/sprite-resource-icons.png) are the current sprite images.